# select multiple checkbox and append its value

Tags: jquery, select, drop-down-menu

Here's the scenario, I have dynamic dropdown button that each time user select it will view the list of name with checkbox into a div;

[image: screenshot]

if the checkbox is checked the value (ids) will append into textarea below; if unchecked it will remove the value.

[image]
:

Problem is every time I select into dropdown and checked an item, all text in textarea are removed. Here's my function:

```
(function($) {
    jQuery.fn.multiselect = function() {
        $(this).each(function() {

            var checkboxes = $(this).find("input:checkbox");
            var selectAll  = $(this).find("input[class='checkAll']");

            selectAll.off('click').on('click', function() {
                $(this).closest('div').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked );
                $(this).closest('div').find(':checkbox').parent().toggleClass("multiselect-on", this.checked);
            });

            checkboxes.each(function() {
                var checkbox = $(this);

                checkboxes.on('change', function() {
                   $(this).parent().toggleClass("multiselect-on", this.checked);
                   var string = checkboxes.filter(":checked").map(function(){
                      return this.value;
                   }).get().join(",");

                   $('#empid').val(string);

                });
            });
        });
    };
    })(jQuery);
```

--thanks to @undefined minimizing the function ;)

[UPDATED] function

Function is now working accordingly with select all option. but the idea must be; if one of the item is unchecked the select all option must be unchecked!

found the same idea in a plugins [Multiple Select](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/) I want to include in the functions

Please help enlighten me again! ;(

Comment: Please provide all the code in the question's context, how do you set the dropdown, it's listeners, etc.

Comment: why you have written checkbox.click seperately if you can write same logic in checkboxes.on('click'....?

Comment: @aboca Ive used inline onchanged function on select and call the function multiselect

Comment: @Bhushan Kawadkar ive notice that but cant find a way to put it together

Comment: @mrrsb well then every time you change an item from the dropdown it will iterate through the DOM elements at that moment, if you have changed those elements then it won't find them hence it will fill the text in blank because there's no checkbox checked. I might have misunderstood your problem.

Comment: yes @aboca. is there a way to call the function instead of inline?

Comment: @mrrsb easiest way would be to just hide and show the inputs with the dropdown change, then you can initialize multiselect with all the elements and retain it's check

Comment: @Aboca, it would be a big help if you can give me a sample demo? :)

Comment: @mrrsb could you construct a jfiddle with your code? that way I could see the problem easier

Comment: finally got it by just appending the name list then separate them in div and hide/show the list! thanks @Aboca!

Comment: Ive updated the function. Please help :(

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `#chekeditem` selects the target element(*textarea*) correctly you should just use the `val` method instead the `text`. For setting/getting values of form controls `val` method should be used.

Please note that you are attaching several click handlers to the elements in your `each` loop:

```
checkboxes.each(function() {
    ...
    // Add selected checkbox in textarea
    checkboxes.on('click' ...
```

And jQuery `on` method iterates through the collection internally, you don't have to use a loop at first place.

You can also minify the code, there is no need to use several `click`(*better to listen to `change` event*) handlers:

```
checkboxes.on('change', function() {
   $(this).parent().toggleClass("multiselect-on", this.checked);

   var string = checkboxes.filter(":checked").map(function(){
      return this.value;
   }).get().join(",");

   $('#chekeditem').val(string);
});
```

If the handler should be called immediately after event binding you can trigger the event using `change()`, `trigger('eventName')`, or `triggerHandler()` method.

```
checkboxes.on('change', function() {}).change();
```

Comment: thanks for pointing that. checkboxes.on('click'.. is used to highlight the checkbox

Comment: thanks @undefined! now problem is how to retain the value in textarea

Comment: Ive call the function and apply it to DOM. maybe you have a better way to append it to DOM? :)

Comment: in my select dropdown. I called the a function selectchanged() where this function populate the list of names. `code`<select name="deptid" id="deptid" onchange="javascript:selectchanged('url','formId','taregtDiv');selectfilter();">Select Team</select>, and then I call also the selectfilter() where the fn.multiselect take place.